# One Class SVM using LibSVM in Matlab - Conceptual

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, libsvm, outliers

Perhaps this is an easy question, but I want to make sure I understand the conceptual basis of the LibSVM implementation of one-class SVMs and if what I am doing is permissible.

I am using one class SVMs in this case for outlier detection and removal. This is used in the context of a greater time series prediction model as a data preprocessing step. That said, I have a Y vector (which is the quantity we are trying to predict and is continuous, not class labels) and an X matrix (continuous features used to predict). Since I want to detect outliers in the data early in the preprocessing step, I have yet to normalize or lag the X matrix for use in prediction, or for that matter detrend/remove noise/or otherwise process the Y vector (which is already scaled to within [-1,1]). My main question is whether it is correct to model the one class SVM like so (using libSVM):

```
svmod = svmtrain(ones(size(Y,1),1),Y,'-s 2 -t 2 -g 0.00001 -n 0.01');
[od,~,~] = svmpredict(ones(size(Y,1),1),Y,svmod);
```

The resulting model does yield performance somewhat in line with what I would expect (99% or so prediction accuracy, meaning 1% of the observations are outliers). But why I ask is because in other questions regarding one class SVMs, people appear to be using their X matrices where I use Y. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing here is nothing more than a fancy range check. *If you are not willing to use `X` to find outliers in `Y`* (even though you really should), it would be a lot simpler and better to just check the distribution of `Y` to find outliers instead of this improvised SVM solution (for example remove the upper and lower 0.5-percentiles from `Y`).

In reality, this is probably not even close to what you *really* want to do. With this setup you are rejecting `Y` values as outliers without considering any context (e.g. `X`). Why are you using RBF and how did you come up with that specific value for `gamma`? A kernel is total overkill for one-dimensional data.

Secondly, you are training and testing on the same data (`Y`). A kitten dies every time this happens. One-class SVM attempts to build a model which recognizes the training data, it should not be used on the same data it was built with. Please, think of the kittens.

---

Additionally, note that the `nu` parameter of one-class SVM controls the amount of outliers the classifier will accept. This is explained in the [LIBSVM implementation document](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) (page 4): *It is proved that `nu` is an upper bound on the fraction of training errors and
a lower bound of the fraction of support vectors*. In other words: your training options specifically state that up to 1% of the data can be rejected. For one-class SVM, replace *can* by *should*.

So when you say that *the resulting model does yield performance somewhat in line with what I would expect* ... ofcourse it does, by definition. Since you have set `nu=0.01`, 1% of the data is rejected by the model and thus flagged as an outlier.